# Trying to upload multiple arrays of data with similar column fields to one mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure how to ask this. I"m using php and mysql. I have multiple arrays of data that have similar information in them, the unique difference is that they all have a different categoryID that I am sending via an input hidden. I tested building and inserting arrays into mysql with a foreach loop, but only with one array of data, and it worked. However, I'm not sure how to do this with multiple tables where most of the columns have the same names and the categoryID is the differentiator. Below is an example of the data I'm trying to send and some of the column names. I'm trying to do all of this via one form.

```
>Table 1 to insert
>day1    day2    score  nameID  money   other   categoryID
>10      10      20     1       100     yes     1
>5       5       10     22      50      sure    1

>Table 2 to insert
>score  nameID  money   other   categoryID
>44     5      100              2
>55     89     44       no      2

>Table 3 to insert
>day1    day2    score  nameID  money   other   categoryID
>100     100     200    67      1000    no      3
>55      55      110    5       600     blah    3
```

Any clues as to what I should try to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated. Adding code samples of single array that works.

```
<table width='550' id='openResults' border='1' cellpadding='0'  cellspacing='0'>

    <tr>
          <td width="150"><input size="5" type="text" name="score[]"></td>
          <td width="150"><input size="5" type="text" name="name[]"></td>
          <td width="150"><input size="5" type="text" name="rsAmount[]"></td>
          <td width="100">&nbsp;</td></tr>

</table>



foreach ($_POST['name'] as $key =>$name) {
    $score=$_POST['score'][$key];
    $rsamount=$_POST['rsAmount'][$key];
    echo "<tr><td width='50'>$score</td><td width='50'>$name</td><td width='50'>$rsamount</td></tr>";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO testRows (score, name, rsAmount) VALUES ('$score', '$name', '$rsamount')";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error in query: $sql. " . mysql_error());
 }
```

Comment: I think it would help if you could show some more code, specifically the loop you successfully wrote for one array and outline how this needs to be different. Also might help to see the form, unless I'm misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: How about using the same `name` tag (i.e maybe the money input tag, in all of the HTML tables, would have a name like `name=money[]`. Then, the foreach loop would insert money input values for the tree tables.

Comment: my single array foreach loop does that as each row must have a name, it populated the table really strange, I guess I can continue to look at that and try to figure out why it did what it did. Not all the arrays might get input, that is why I'm trying to figure out how to do this based on the categoryID. I tried if($_POSt['categoryID'] == 1) { do the forloop but this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all this is untested so you might need to fiddle with it, but hope it helps a little...

Try reformatting your inputs to include the id in the index like this:

```
      <td width="150"><input size="5" type="text" name="score[1][]"></td>
      <td width="150"><input size="5" type="text" name="name[1][]"></td>
      <td width="150"><input size="5" type="text" name="rsAmount[1][]"></td>
```

Then when you loop you can add a 2nd level to get the category ID from the [1] above:

```
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $categoyId => $data) {
  foreach ($data as $key =>$placeholder) {
    $name=$_POST['name'][$categoryId][$key];
    $score=$_POST['score'][$categoryId][$key];
    $rsamount=$_POST['rsAmount'][$categoryId][$key];
    echo "<tr><td width='50'>$score</td><td width='50'>$name</td><td width='50'>$rsamount</td></tr>";
    switch ($categoyId) {
       case 1:
          $sql = "INSERT INTO table_1 (score, name, rsAmount) VALUES ('$score', '$name', '$rsamount')";
          break;   
       case 2:
          $sql = "INSERT INTO table_2 (score, name, whatver) VALUES ('$score', '$name', '$rsamount')";
          break;   
       case 3:

          $sql = "INSERT INTO table_3 (score, name, somethingElse) VALUES ('$score', '$name', '$rsamount')";
          break;
       defaut: 
           $sql = null;
    }
    if ($sql) {
       $result2 = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error in query: $sql. " . mysql_error());
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: This is really close, first array works good, second inserts everything but last row. So I'm gonna play with it to see if I can get it to work